# Sign dependencies with maven

Tags: java, maven, japplet

I need to sign the project dependencies using maven. I'm working on an applet and managed to sign the main jar but my dependencies are not signed at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the [jarsigner](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/) plugin?